# Media Recorder Start Failed -19 on Nexus 9 Android Lollipop 5.1.1

Tags: android, camera, android-camera, android-mediarecorder, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I am trying to capture video in my app.
This was working fine on all android versions and different devices until I tried it on Nexus 9 with Android Version 5.1.1.

**This is my code:**

```
                prCamera.lock();
                prCamera.unlock();
                prMediaRecorder.setCamera(prCamera);
                prMediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
                prMediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
                prMediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
                prMediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(AudioEncoder.AAC);
                prMediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(VideoEncoder.H264);
                prRecordedFile = new File(mFilePath);
                prMediaRecorder.setOutputFile(prRecordedFile.getPath());
                prMediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(3000000);
                prMediaRecorder.setVideoSize(720, 480);
                prMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(cFrameRate);
                prMediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(prSurfaceHolder.getSurface());
                prMediaRecorder.prepare();
                if (prRecordedFile.exists()) {
                    prRecordedFile.mkdirs();
                    if (MarkerName != null) {
                        try {
                            prMediaRecorder.start(); // EXITS HERE
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();  // STACK TRACE SHOWN BELOW
                        }
                    }
                }
```

**This is Log (Stack Trace):**

```
06-24 12:42:20.099: W/System.err(10736): java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
06-24 12:42:20.138: W/System.err(10736):    at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(Native Method)
06-24 12:42:20.206: W/System.err(10736):    at uk.org.humanfocus.hfi.FFMPEGRecorderActivity.startRecording(FFMPEGRecorderActivity.java:1083)
06-24 12:42:20.260: W/System.err(10736):    at uk.org.humanfocus.hfi.FFMPEGRecorderActivity.access$15(FFMPEGRecorderActivity.java:1035)
06-24 12:42:20.304: W/System.err(10736):    at uk.org.humanfocus.hfi.FFMPEGRecorderActivity$5.run(FFMPEGRecorderActivity.java:1300)
06-24 12:42:20.344: W/System.err(10736):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
06-24 12:42:20.384: W/System.err(10736):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
06-24 12:42:20.417: W/System.err(10736):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
06-24 12:42:20.467: W/System.err(10736):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
06-24 12:42:20.504: W/System.err(10736):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-24 12:42:20.547: W/System.err(10736):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
06-24 12:42:20.594: W/System.err(10736):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
06-24 12:42:20.630: W/System.err(10736):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: Would the down-voters please justify themselves?

Answer (score 0):

Please Remove this line and try again.

```
prMediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(cFrameRate);
```